# Can we create method with generic return type and how does this evaluate which type to return at compile time?

Tags: java, generics

I see compiler allowing following method. But can anyone explain how the return type will be decided at compile time.And what will be the value of T. 
Also can you give me reference document or video where I can understand further on how the generic type will be decided internally by java compiler.

```
public <T> T getValue(String abc) throws Exception {
        if(abc.equals("x")){
            return (T) new String[]{"x","y","z"};
        } else {
            return (T) "abc";
        }
    }
```

Comment: `T` is specified by the caller of the method. If `T` is not compatible with the object the method tries to return, you will get an exception at run-time.

Comment: @khelwood In above scenario, how does caller specifies T ? It is used only in return type..

Comment: Something like `instance.<Object>getValue("x")` for instance. Why not try calling the method and see how it works?

Comment: @khelwood, ok. did not know we can call like that as well. I  will explore on that. thanks .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is type erasure process at the compile time. From javadoc:

> During the type erasure process, the Java compiler erases all type parameters and replaces each with its first bound if the type parameter is bounded, or Object if the type parameter is unbounded

So, in your examples all `T` will be replaces by `Object` type. But during the execution time it will be casted to the type you specified. For example:

```
Integer value = obj.<Integer>getValue("string");
```

There is no compile time error, but at the runtime it will try to apply casting `return (Integer) "abc";` and you will get `ClassCastException`

See more about [**Erasure Generic type**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypes.html) and [**Erasure of Generic Methods**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genMethods.html)

Comment: The cast to `Integer` isn't done in the return statement. It's done when you use the return value (e.g. `Integer a = obj.getValue("");`), and not for the statement e.g. `obj.<Integer>getValue("");`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this generically.

The best you can do is to use a non-generic method, returning a common superclass - in this case, `Object`:

```
public Object getValue(String abc) throws Exception {
    if(abc.equals("x")){
        return new String[]{"x","y","z"};
    } else {
        return "abc";
    }
}
```

This places the burden onto the caller to cast the object to the appropriate type, which you might balk at. But note that your current method also does that, because there is nothing to stop them from writing this:

```
String s = getValue("x");
String[] arr = getValue("x");
```

Both of these are fine, but one of them will fail at runtime. The caller has to somehow know which of the invocations will return a `String`, and which will return a `String[]`.

The advantage of forcing *them* to do the casting is that then they can see the cast, and know that they are going to have to take care.

A better approach would be to return a value of the same type in all cases: return `new String[]{"abc"}` instead.